# ON a rainy day or FOR a rainy day?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

1. What are the best foods to have *on* a rainy day?
2. What are the best foods to have *for* a rainy day?

Which preposition would be appropriate here?

Comment: The phrase _for a rainy day_ is usually used metaphorically in expressions like 'put money aside for a rainy day'. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-rainy-day

Comment: It isn't about rain, but unfortunate circumstances. Bob: "I didn't get paid so we can't eat!" Alice: "Don't worry, I put aside some dried noodles and canned soup **for** a rainy day." More generally, "it's raining" doesn't always mean it is literally raining, for example the song lyrics "It's raining in my heart."

Answer (score -2):

What are the best foods to have on a rainy day? = food eaten on days with rain.

What are the best foods to have for a rainy day? = food that is stored or held in reserve to be eaten on days with rain